# Is there any relation between moments of random matrix and its eigenvalue distribution?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, random-matrices

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be a random matrix with independent Gaussian random variable entries with different variances $v_{ij}$. Also define $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{X}^\mathrm{H}\mathbf{X}$. Is there any relation between the distribution of the eigenvalues of $\mathbf{A}$ and moments of $\mathbf{A}$, i.e.,
$$\mathbf{B}_m=\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{A}^m]$$ for integers $m\geq 1$?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the notion of a moment being matrix-valued. Are you sure you don't mean something like ${\rm Tr}((A^m)^*A^m)$?

Comment: Moreover, can you specify what class of random matrices you are considering? Square? Symmetric/hermitian? etc

Comment: If, as Yemon Choi suspects, your moments of $\mathbf{A} $ are traces of powers thereof, then you can just calculate them in the eigenbasis, where they are directly moments of the eigenvalue distribution.

Comment: What is the relation between $\mathrm{Tr}[A^m]$ and eigenvalue distribution? Could you please explain with more details?

Comment: the expectation of ${\rm tr}\, A^m$ depends only on the marginal distribution of a single eigenvalue, so it contains no information on the correlations between the eigenvalues.

Comment: If you know the eigenvalue distribution $\rho_{A} (\lambda )$, then $\mbox{Tr} [A^m] = \int d\lambda \lambda^{m} \rho_{A} (\lambda )$. This is even true for a single matrix $A$, before averaging over an ensemble.